# In Angular2 routing, the URL changed but the content doesn't update

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am a beginner of Angular2. When I am learning angular2 routing service from https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5. I want to have herocomponent always displayed so I  in the app.component.html like this:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
  <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
  <a routerLink="/dummy">Dummy</a>
</nav>
<app-heroes></app-heroes>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-messages></app-messages>
```

And here is the app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import {DummyComponentComponent} from './dummy-component/dummy-component.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent },
  {path: 'dummy',component:DummyComponentComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Strangely, when I click a hero on `/dashboard` or `/heroes` page it can direct to the correct URL and show the correct hero detail.

However, when I am on `/detail/{{hero.id}}` and click the hero on the hero component it can redirect the URL but the content in  doesn't update. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: can you please share code at stackbiz...that might help to resolve it

Comment: hi added my answer can you please try out

Comment: is that worked for you ?? can you please let me know

Comment: updated my answer , have try it should work

Answer (score 2):

if below is not issue then it should be issue that you are just changing parameter url that is reason its not updating

```
//put this code in your hero.component.ts file 
ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
   this.id = +params['id'];
   this.loadComponentAgain();
 });
}
```

above code monitor change in param value and update your component according to it.

---

There is issue because of this html

```
<app-heroes></app-heroes>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

you are loading `app-heroes` component out side `router-outlet`, it should be loaded under `router-outlet`, so you should do this

```
<!-- <app-heroes></app-heroes> remove this-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: That is not what I am asking. I keep app-heroes because I always want to have the hero list displayed. The problem is the content inside router-outlet doesn’t change

Comment: @LinLi - its hard to get why its not changing without seeing your code can you please share it some where ,

Answer (score 1):

For changing a route with dynamic value you need to set your routerLink like this

```
[routerLink]="['/detail',hero.id]"
```